# text preprocessing using string operations on tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, tensor

I am trying to write a function that takes two string tensors from Keras input layers and do some string operations on them.

My first question is how to loop over each item in the tensors and split the first input (full sentence) using the second input (phrase of two words) and retrieve the indices of the split words.

```
Sentence = "this is an example to split on this dummy phrase and get an index"
Phrase = "this dummy phrase"
output = [7, 9]
```

The function that I have (which  deals with strings)

```
def get_phrase_inside_sentence_indices(sentence, phrase):
    split_sentence = sentence.split(phrase)
    split_phrase_len = len(phrase.split(" "))

     first_part_of_sentence = split_sentence[0].strip().split(" ")
     second_index = split_phrase_len + len(first_part_of_sentence ) - 1     
     first_index = find_reverse_index(first_part_of_sentence, first_part_of_sentence [-1]) + 1
    return first_index, second_index

def find_reverse_index(given_list, value):
    return len(given_list) - given_list[-1::-1].index(value) - 1
```

How to convert this function to work on tensors or to loop over tensors and apply this function. I have a batch of sentences of (256,1) and a batch of corresponding phrases of (256,1) as my inputs.

My second question is how to convert the tensor to be a unicoded string:
The output from the layer is:

```
tf.Tensor([[b'this is an example to split on this dummy phrase and get an index']...], shape=(256, 1), dtype=string)
```

but I want to get rid of the "b" at the beginning.

Comment: What does `find_reverse_index` do?

Comment: Also would you have a batch of strings in `sentence` and a single separator in `phrase`, or a batch of `sentence` and a batch of `phrase`? Btw about your second question, TensorFlow does not support Unicode or any text encoding as such, `tf.string` tensors are really just `bytes`. You can decode the bytes into a string after computing the result, when you need to write it out somewhere (although now there are functions like [`tf.string.unicode_decode`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/unicode_decode) to get Unicode codepoints).

Comment: Yes i will have a batch of sentences and a batch of corresponding phrases. I will update the question to include `find_reverse_index` but basically it get the index of the first word in the phrase from the sentence.